# Как сделать удаление старых сообщений при достижении определенного их количества?

Tags: php

есть код, при выполнении которого в файл записывается новая строчка производного текста:

```
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "тут текст\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

как сделать так, чтобы показывались только 50 последних сообщений (т.е. при добавлении 51 сообщения удалялось 1, а при 52 - 2 и т.д.)?

Answer (score 1):

В теории, если учесть, что каждое сообщение - это каждая строка, тогда делаем следующие:

1. Проверяем количество новых сообщений которых будем записывать;
2. Проверяем сколько записей в файле;
3. Проверяем, есть ли у нас место для записи, если есть записываем и не удаляем не чего. В противном случае удаляем первую(-ые) строчки.

Алгоритм удаление одной строчки, также простой. Для этого открываем файл через функцию file. Эта функция если не ошибаюсь, каждую строчку берет как элемент массива. И просто напросто пишем код, что-то вроде такого:

```
    $file = file('data.txt');
    unset($file[0]);
    $file = implode('\n', $file);
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $file);
    //...
```